# Excel formula to get max length of delimited value in a cell

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have a single cell which contains multiple lines of text delimited by carriage return CHAR(10).

```
Cell A1 = "First line of text
Second line of text
Third line"
```

I need to know the length of the longest row (19), using a formula not VBA (this excel can't have macros).

Any help someone can provide to solve this problem and ideally explain what it's doing would be appreciated as I genuinely want to understand what I'm putting in not just copy/paste, I consider myself an advanced excel user and would take me a few mins in VBA, and have created complex formulas before, but I've never been able to understand arrays in excel formulas..

**My babble:**

I'm guessing that I need to create an array using mid in the absence of the split vba function, then use =max(len({array})).

But I just don't really understand arrays in excel, I can't seem to get my head around them and how I can iterate through values.. In my simple mind I just want to be able increment X in the below from 1 to the length of A1 this would give me an array of lengths between X character and the next carriage return and as I'm only looking for the max then the incorrect shorter lengths aren't relevant, i'd also need to catch non numeric results from the find (I've just left this out so it's easier to see what I'm saying and it's likely irrelevant anyway as I don't think this is how arrays work!

`{=max(FIND(CHAR(10),A1&CHAR(10),X)-X)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MID to parse the string breaking on the Char(10) and return the max

```
=MAX(LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:20)-1)*999+1,999))))
```

Depending on your version this needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode as it is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: So I get that this is subbing in 999 spaces then using mid to select the block and trim to then remove the spaces.. but what is making it iterate? ROW(1:20) ? if so if I have more that 20 rows would this need to be a higher number? Sorry just trying to understand for my own sanity how the iteration in to the array takes place!

Comment: @n3rding yes that is correct that is what is iterating, just set it to the max number of lines you will have.

Comment: Hey, I used this one in the end, working perfectly and handled "&" which the current XML one didn't, thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3):

If you have Excel 2013+, you can create an XML and then use the `FILTERXML` function to parse the lines.  The `LEN` function will return the length of each line.

```
=MAX(LEN(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s")))
```

Depending on your version of Excel, you will confirm the formula with just <kbd>enter</kbd> , or by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image]

**EDIT:**

To account for characters that need to be "escaped" in an XML, we just need to make a few substitutions.

There are only two characters that need to be "escaped" in a text string. Since we are counting the length of the line, I replaced them with a tilde (and not with the escape code).

```
=MAX(LEN(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<","~"),"&","~"),CHAR(10),"</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!, Will need to check as used across multiple organisations.. but might be an option though as I think they are all 365

Comment: @n3rding Then they should all have that function.

Comment: So I didn't use this one in the end, but only because one of the examples I used it on had an "&" which caused it to fail, but otherwise worked perfectly!

Comment: @n3rding There's a simple fix for that. I'll post it later today.

Comment: @n3rding See my edit for the fix for characters that need to be escaped in an xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
=MID(A2,LEN(A2)+1-MATCH(MAX(FIND(CHAR(10),(RIGHT(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))&CHAR(10)))),FIND(CHAR(10),(RIGHT(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))&CHAR(10))),0),MAX(FIND(CHAR(10),(RIGHT(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))&CHAR(10))))-1)
```

Then modify with LEN

```
=LEN(MID(A2,LEN(A2)+1-MATCH(MAX(FIND(CHAR(10),(RIGHT(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))&CHAR(10)))),FIND(CHAR(10),(RIGHT(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))&CHAR(10))),0),MAX(FIND(CHAR(10),(RIGHT(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))&CHAR(10))))-1))
```

CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after you paste it.

source: https://www.listendata.com/2015/10/excel-find-longest-word-in-cell.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll re-check this, but I think the solution may be simpler as the length calc is already taking place in the formula, so adding len is the easy option, but I think the formula can be simplified.. I'll give it a go tomorrow

Comment: Yeah this might be a good option for earlier versions of excel. But I really like Ron's answer because its using a clearer formula